# Failed to start thermal deamon service and Failed to start CUPS service. Failed: READ FPDMA queued

Tags: boot, hard-drive, printing, 22.10, cups-lpd

I am getting a couple of error/failed messages while starting Ubuntu. It was working fine, but suddenly it got shutdown. When I restarted it was taking time, but it was not able to start and then after some time I got error messages.

```
Failed to start thermal daemon service
Failed to start CUPS service. 
Failed: READ FPDMA queued.
```

and a couple more. I am not sure what these mean. How can I start the laptop?

[image]

Comment: First what version of Ubuntu are you using? Second it appears you OS has corrupted. What caused the shut down?

Comment: The 3 rd error down is a hard drive problem. Yes serious either the hard drive has failed or as I said the OS is corrupted.

Comment: I was using Chrome and it suddenly shut down.  I have no idea why it shut down. I had restored the database earlier. It was done without any problem and after that, I used chrome and then it got shut down. I am using the 22.04 version of Ubuntu.

Comment: With no warning and a sudden shut down like that more info that says HD failed.